# Reinforcement learning: Is Actor-Critic alwayse better than Policy gradient method?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am new to reinforcement learning and I want to try code my own small library and I have wondered if exist any reason to implement policy gradients.

THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

Actor-critic is a type of policy gradient algorithm. Unless you are using some terminology that is different from what I'm used to.

In a policy gradient algorithm, we take a policy parameterized on some parameters, find the gradient of the policy based on the actions taken and then update the policy parameters towards the gradient.

Actor critic does exactly that.

In actor-critic the value function is also calculated and affects the update. But, it is still a policy gradient algorithm.